# Query taking hell lot of time

Tags: performance, oracle, stored-procedures, timeout

our system is quite big having around 100+ tables in schema. There was one business requirement for which we decided to handle it in stored procedures. In our application we have java as well but we chosen to use Stored Procedure. IN order to fulfill requirement created 3 functions.
These functions are part of SQL query which get fired to fetch count and display records. Now we have SQL timeout set in connection which is set to 60 seconds. 
when we run this query for records of 40K, the operation gets timed out and we don't get any result. 
I am pasting here actual implementation of all these 3 functions and below them is query who makes use of all these created function.

In query below have marked function calling in Bold letter.

I am looking at your expert advice by which i can tune this implementation to work on 100K of data. 
we have oracle 11gR1..  Even this implementation is access from web in Ajax call.

Do let me know if you need anything else.

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_SNM_ENTITY_NAME
  ON SML_NOTIFICATION_MAIN(ENTITY_NAME)
  TABLESPACE CM_INDEX;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_Users_In_Same_Business_Unit
    (UserMasterId varchar2,
     CtoCode varchar2)       
  RETURN boolean
IS 
  v_count number(4);       
BEGIN
  if CtoCode is not null then       
    select count(*) into v_count
      from sml_user u,
           sml_team_member tm,
           sml_usrprof_cto_map ctomap,
           code_value cv
      where u.status = 'ACTIVE'
        and u.master_id is null
        and u.id = tm.user_id
        and tm.profile_id = ctomap.user_profile_id
        and ctomap.cto_code_id = cv.id
        and cv.code_value = CtoCode
        and tm.team_id in
              (select child_id
                 from vw_team_relation_master a
                 connect by prior a.child_id = a.parent_id
                 start with a.child_id =
                   (select child_id
                      from vw_team_relation_master c
                      where parent_id is null
                      start with c.child_id =
                        (select t.id
                           from sml_team t,
                                sml_team_member tm
                           where t.id = tm.team_id
                             and t.status = 'ACTIVE'
                             and t.master_id is null
                             and tm.user_id = UserMasterId) 
                      connect by prior c.parent_id = c.child_id));

    if v_count is not null and v_count > 0 then
      return TRUE;
    else
      return FALSE;
    end if;       
  end if;        

  return FALSE;           
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Can_User_Access_Customer(
      NotificationDesc            VARCHAR2,
      UserId                      VARCHAR2,
      NotificationType            VARCHAR2,
      UserRoleCode                VARCHAR2,
      UserMasterId                VARCHAR2,
      CtoCode                     VARCHAR2,
      SecCtoCode                  VARCHAR2,
      UserProfTempIdCommercialInd VARCHAR2,
      UserProfTempIdCorporateInd  VARCHAR2,
      UserProfTempStcfInd         VARCHAR2,
      UserProfTempIdGsamInd       VARCHAR2)
    RETURN BOOLEAN
IS
  -- function to test is user can access customer
  regSearchCount                number(2);
  in_same_unit                  boolean;
  count_v                       number(2);
BEGIN
  in_same_unit := is_Users_In_Same_Business_Unit(UserMasterId, CtoCode);

  -- Commercial    

  select count(*)
    into regSearchCount
    from dual
    where regexp_like (CtoCode,'200[3-9]|20[1-4][0-9]|2[1-6][0-6][0-9]|29[0-6][0-9]|300[1-9]|30[1-6][0-9]|3[1-9][0-6][0-9]');        

  IF regSearchCount > 0 then -- user is commercial
    -- check secondary cto code holder
    select count(*)
      into count_v
      from dual
      where SecCtoCode IN
        (SELECT DISTINCT code_value
           FROM sml_user,
                sml_team_member,
                sml_user_profile,
                sml_usrprof_cto_map,
                code_value
           WHERE sml_user.id = sml_team_member.user_id
             AND sml_team_member.profile_id = sml_user_profile.id
             AND sml_user_profile.id = sml_usrprof_cto_map.user_profile_id
             AND sml_usrprof_cto_map.cto_code_id = code_value.id
             AND sml_user.login_id = UserId);

    IF count_v is not null AND
       count_v > 0
    then
      return TRUE;
    END IF;

    IF NotificationType='Collateral' AND
       UserRoleCode is not null AND
       UserRoleCode='RLOC'
    then -- user is rloc
      RETURN TRUE;
    END IF;

    IF in_same_unit AND
       UserRoleCode is not null AND
       UserRoleCode IN ('RMTL','GRPHD','SECHD')
    then -- user belongs to GH, SH etc          
      RETURN TRUE;
    END IF;
  END IF;     

  -- corporate

  select count(*)
    into regSearchCount
    from dual
    where regexp_like (CtoCode,'1[0-9][0-6][0-9]');

  IF regSearchCount > 0 then
    IF in_same_unit and UserRoleCode is not null AND
       UserRoleCode='GRPHD' AND
       NotificationDesc!='0 days Due for expiry of Collateral'
     THEN -- user belongs to GH          
        RETURN TRUE;                    
    END IF;

    IF in_same_unit AND
       UserRoleCode is not null AND
       UserRoleCode='RMTL' AND
       NotificationDesc='0 days Due for expiry of Collateral'
    THEN
        RETURN TRUE;                    
    END IF;
  END IF;    

  -- STCF     

  select count(*)
    into regSearchCount
    from dual
    where regexp_like (CtoCode, '20[5-6][0-9]');

  IF regSearchCount > 0 then      
    IF in_same_unit AND
       UserRoleCode is not null AND
       UserRoleCode = 'RMTL'
    then
      RETURN TRUE;          
    END IF;
  END IF;    

  RETURN FALSE ;
END;

create or replace FUNCTION IS_NOTIFICATION_ACCESS_PASSED(
      NotificationDesc            VARCHAR2,
      UserId                      VARCHAR2,
      NotificationType            VARCHAR2,
      UserMasterId                VARCHAR2,
      UserRoleCode                VARCHAR2,
      CtoCode                     VARCHAR2,
      SecCtoCode                  VARCHAR2,
      UserProfTempIdCommercialInd VARCHAR2,
      UserProfTempIdCorporateInd  VARCHAR2,
      UserProfTempStcfInd         VARCHAR2,
      UserProfTempIdGsamInd       VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
IS
  -- functions to test, is instance of notification viewable for the logged in user, on the basis of notification type
  -- and other user details etc, currently defined for only type 'Collateral' and 'Implementation Instruction'

  regSearchCount NUMBER(2);
  count_v NUMBER(2);       
BEGIN
  IF NotificationType = 'Implementation Instruction' THEN
    IF Can_User_Access_Customer(NotificationDesc,UserId,
                                NotificationType
                                UserRoleCode,UserMasterId
                                CtoCode,SecCtoCode,
                                UserProfTempIdCommercialInd,
                                UserProfTempIdCorporateInd,
                                UserProfTempStcfInd,
                                UserProfTempIdGsamInd)
    THEN
      IF UserRoleCode = 'LDU' THEN
        SELECT COUNT(*)
          INTO regSearchCount
          FROM dual
          WHERE regexp_like (CtoCode,'1[0-9][0-6][0-9]');

        IF regSearchCount >0 THEN
          RETURN 'TRUE';
        ELSE
          RETURN 'FALSE';
        END IF;
      ELSE
        RETURN 'TRUE';
      END IF;
    END IF;
  END IF;

  IF NotificationType = 'Collateral' THEN
    IF UserRoleCode   ='WLOC' THEN
      RETURN 'TRUE';
    END IF;

    -- check primary cto code holder

    select count(*)
      into count_v
      from dual
      where CtoCode IN
        (SELECT DISTINCT code_value
           FROM sml_user,
                sml_team_member,
                sml_user_profile,
                sml_usrprof_cto_map,
                code_value
           WHERE sml_user.id = sml_team_member.user_id
             AND sml_team_member.profile_id = sml_user_profile.id
             AND sml_user_profile.id = sml_usrprof_cto_map.user_profile_id
             AND sml_usrprof_cto_map.cto_code_id = code_value.id
             AND sml_user.login_id = UserId);

    IF count_v is not null and count_v > 0 then
      return 'TRUE';
    END IF;

    -- check all other conditions

    IF Can_User_Access_Customer(NotificationDesc,UserId,NotificationType,
                                UserRoleCode,UserMasterId,CtoCode,
                                SecCtoCode,UserProfTempIdCommercialInd,
                                UserProfTempIdCorporateInd,
                                UserProfTempStcfInd,
                                UserProfTempIdGsamInd) THEN
      RETURN 'TRUE';
    END IF;
  ELSE
    RETURN 'TRUE';
  END IF;

  RETURN 'FALSE';
END;
```

The query:

```
select *
  FROM SML_NOTIFICATION_MAIN notification
  where notification.DEPRECATED='N'  and
        (MAKER_ID = 'see_rm'  OR
         TO_CHAR(CTO_CODE) IN
           (SELECT DISTINCT code_value
              FROM sml_user, 
                   sml_team_member,
                   sml_user_profile,
                   sml_usrprof_cto_map,
                   code_value
              WHERE sml_user.id = sml_team_member.user_id AND
                    sml_team_member.profile_id = sml_user_profile.id AND
                    sml_user_profile.id = sml_usrprof_cto_map.user_profile_id AND
                    sml_usrprof_cto_map.cto_code_id = code_value.id AND
                    sml_user.login_id = 'see_rm' AND
                    Entity_Name != 'Collateral') OR
        TO_CHAR(SEC_CTO_CODE) IN
          (SELECT DISTINCT code_value
             FROM sml_user, 
                  sml_team_member,
                  sml_user_profile,
                  sml_usrprof_cto_map,
                  code_value 
             WHERE sml_user.id = sml_team_member.user_id AND 
                   sml_team_member.profile_id = sml_user_profile.id AND
                   sml_user_profile.id = sml_usrprof_cto_map.user_profile_id AND
                   sml_usrprof_cto_map.cto_code_id = code_value.id AND
                   Entity_Name != 'Collateral' AND
                   sml_user.login_id ='see_rm') OR
        ROLE_CODE in (select distinct CODE
                        from sml_user a,
                             code_value b
                        where a.role_id = b.id AND
                              login_id = 'see_rm') OR
        SUBSTR(ROLE_CODE, 1, 4) in (select distinct CODE
                                    from sml_user a,
                                         code_value b
                                    where a.role_id = b.id AND
                                          login_id = 'see_rm') OR
        SUBSTR(ROLE_CODE, 6, 4) IN (select distinct CODE
                                      from sml_user a,
                                           code_value b
                                      where ENTITY_NAME = 'Insurance' OR
                                            ENTITY_NAME = 'Collateral' AND
                                            a.role_id = b.id AND
                                            login_id = 'see_rm') OR
        SUBSTR(ROLE_CODE, 11, 2) IN (select distinct CODE
                                       from sml_user a,
                                            code_value b
                                       where a.role_id = b.id AND
                                             login_id = 'see_rm') OR 
        TEAM_LEAD in (select to_char(a.id)
                        from sml_user a
                        where Entity_Name != 'Collateral' AND
                              a.login_id = 'see_rm') OR
        RM_ID in (select to_char(a.id)
                    from sml_user a
                    where Entity_Name != 'Collateral' AND
                          ENTITY_NAME = 'PostApproval CP/Covnent' AND
                          DESCRIPTION != '30 days before due date' AND
                          a.login_id = 'see_rm') OR
        (Entity_Name != 'Collateral' AND
         RM_ID in (Select Rm_Id
                     From Vw_Sm_Rm_Team_Lead
                     Where Vw_Sm_Rm_Team_Lead.Rmtl_Id IN
                       (Select To_Char(A.Id)
                          From Sml_User A
                          Where A.Login_Id = 'see_rm'))) OR
        (Entity_Name = 'Enquiry' AND
         RM_ID IN (SELECT BCA_ID
                     FROM VW_SM_BCA_TEAM_LEAD
                     WHERE VW_SM_BCA_TEAM_LEAD.BCATL_ID IN
                       (SELECT TO_CHAR(A.Id)
                          FROM Sml_User A 
                          WHERE A.Login_Id = 'see_rm'))) OR
         GROUP_HEAD in (select to_char(a.id)
                          from sml_user a
                          where a.login_id = 'see_rm' AND
                                Entity_Name != 'Collateral') OR
        (Entity_name != 'Collateral' AND
         SECTOR_HEAD like ('%,'|| (select to_char(a.id) || ',' as ID
                                     from sml_user a
                                     where a.login_id = 'see_rm' AND
                                           status='ACTIVE' AND
                                           master_id is null) || '%')) OR
        (Entity_Name = 'Collateral' AND
         IS_NOTIFICATION_ACCESS_PASSED(DESCRIPTION,
                                       'see_rm',
                                       Entity_Name,
                                       '1176',
                                       'RM',
                                       TO_CHAR(CTO_CODE),
                                       TO_CHAR(SEC_CTO_CODE),
                                       'N','N','N','N') = 'TRUE') OR
        (RM_ID in (select rm_id
                     from VW_SM_RM_TEAM_LEAD
                     where rmtl_id IN (Select Distinct Su.Id As Rmtl_Id
                                         FROM sml_user su
                                         INNER JOIN sml_team_member MEMBER
                                           ON su.id=member.user_id
                                         Inner Join Sml_Team Team
                                           On Member.Team_Id=Team.Id AND
                                              Team.Team_Role_Id =
                                                (SELECT ID
                                                   FROM code_value
                                                   WHERE code='RMTL' AND
                                                         status='ACTIVE' AND
                                                         master_id IS NOT NULL AND
                                                         code_set_value_id =
                                                           (SELECT ID
                                                              FROM code_set
                                                              WHERE CODE = 'TEAM_ROLE' AND
                                                                    master_id IS NOT NULL))
                                         Inner Join Sml_Team_Child PARENT
                                           On Team.Id=Parent.Child_Id
                                         INNER JOIN sml_team_member grop
                                           ON grop.team_id=parent.parent_id
                                         INNER JOIN sml_team st
                                           ON st.id=grop.team_id
                                         Where Su.Status = 'ACTIVE' AND
                                               St.Status='ACTIVE' AND
                                               grop.user_id =
                                                 (select to_char(a.id)
                                                    from sml_user a
                                                    where a.master_id is null AND
                                                          a.status='ACTIVE' AND
                                                          a.login_id = 'see_rm'))) AND
         Entity_Name != 'Collateral' AND
         ((Entity_Name = 'Implementation Instruction' AND
           IS_NOTIFICATION_ACCESS_PASSED(DESCRIPTION,
                                         'see_rm',
                                         Entity_Name,
                                         '1176',
                                         'RM',
                                         TO_CHAR(CTO_CODE),
                                         TO_CHAR(SEC_CTO_CODE),
                                         'N','N','N','N') = 'TRUE') OR 
          (Entity_Name = 'Post Disbursement') OR
          (ENTITY_NAME = 'PostApproval CP/Covnent' AND
           DESCRIPTION = '7 days before due date') OR
          (ENTITY_NAME = 'Facility' AND
           DESCRIPTION != '2 Days Due for expiry of Facility') OR
          (ENTITY_NAME = 'Insurance') OR
          (ENTITY_NAME = 'Call Report' AND
           DESCRIPTION = '2 days before exceeded by 11 months'))))

****************************************Execution plan of above query *****************

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
   0       SELECT STATEMENT Optimizer Mode=ALL_ROWS (Cost=294 Card=17 K Bytes=3 M)
   1    0    FILTER
   2    1      TABLE ACCESS FULL UOBCM.SML_NOTIFICATION_MAIN (Cost=294 Card=37 K Bytes=6 M)
   3    1      FILTER
   4    3        NESTED LOOPS
   5    4          NESTED LOOPS (Cost=47 Card=1 Bytes=80)
   6    5            HASH JOIN (Cost=23 Card=24 Bytes=1 K)
   7    6              NESTED LOOPS (Cost=8 Card=12 Bytes=432)
   8    7                HASH JOIN (Cost=8 Card=12 Bytes=384)
   9    8                  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.SML_USER (Cost=4 Card=3 Bytes=72)
  10    9                    INDEX RANGE SCAN UOBCM.IDX_USR_LOGINID (Cost=1 Card=3)
  11    8                  INDEX FAST FULL SCAN UOBCM.IDX_TMBR_TMUSERPF (Cost=3 Card=1 K Bytes=8 K)
  12    7                INDEX UNIQUE SCAN UOBCM.PK_SML_USER_PROFILE (Cost=0 Card=1 Bytes=4)
  13    6              VIEW UOBCM.index$_join$_005 (Cost=15 Card=1 K Bytes=14 K)
  14   13                HASH JOIN
  15   14                  INDEX FAST FULL SCAN UOBCM.IDX_USRPROFCTO_USRPROF (Cost=6 Card=1 K Bytes=14 K)
  16   14                  INDEX FAST FULL SCAN UOBCM.IDX_USRPROFCTO_CTO (Cost=11 Card=1 K Bytes=14 K)
  17    5            INDEX UNIQUE SCAN UOBCM.PK_CODE_VALUE (Cost=0 Card=1)
  18    4          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.CODE_VALUE (Cost=1 Card=1 Bytes=36)
  19    1      FILTER
  20   19        NESTED LOOPS
  21   20          NESTED LOOPS (Cost=47 Card=1 Bytes=80)
  22   21            HASH JOIN (Cost=23 Card=24 Bytes=1 K)
  23   22              NESTED LOOPS (Cost=8 Card=12 Bytes=432)
  24   23                HASH JOIN (Cost=8 Card=12 Bytes=384)
  25   24                  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.SML_USER (Cost=4 Card=3 Bytes=72)
  26   25                    INDEX RANGE SCAN UOBCM.IDX_USR_LOGINID (Cost=1 Card=3)
  27   24                  INDEX FAST FULL SCAN UOBCM.IDX_TMBR_TMUSERPF (Cost=3 Card=1 K Bytes=8 K)
  28   23                INDEX UNIQUE SCAN UOBCM.PK_SML_USER_PROFILE (Cost=0 Card=1 Bytes=4)
  29   22              VIEW UOBCM.index$_join$_010 (Cost=15 Card=1 K Bytes=14 K)
  30   29                HASH JOIN
  31   30                  INDEX FAST FULL SCAN UOBCM.IDX_USRPROFCTO_USRPROF (Cost=6 Card=1 K Bytes=14 K)
  32   30                  INDEX FAST FULL SCAN UOBCM.IDX_USRPROFCTO_CTO (Cost=11 Card=1 K Bytes=14 K)
  33   21            INDEX UNIQUE SCAN UOBCM.PK_CODE_VALUE (Cost=0 Card=1)
  34   20          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.CODE_VALUE (Cost=1 Card=1 Bytes=36)
  35    1      NESTED LOOPS
  36   35        NESTED LOOPS (Cost=5 Card=1 Bytes=39)
  37   36          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.SML_USER (Cost=3 Card=3 Bytes=75)
  38   37            INDEX RANGE SCAN UOBCM.IDX_USR_LOGINID (Cost=1 Card=3)
  39   36          INDEX UNIQUE SCAN UOBCM.PK_CODE_VALUE (Cost=0 Card=1)
  40   35        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.CODE_VALUE (Cost=1 Card=1 Bytes=14)
  41    1      NESTED LOOPS
  42   41        NESTED LOOPS (Cost=5 Card=1 Bytes=39)
  43   42          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.SML_USER (Cost=3 Card=3 Bytes=75)
  44   43            INDEX RANGE SCAN UOBCM.IDX_USR_LOGINID (Cost=1 Card=3)
  45   42          INDEX UNIQUE SCAN UOBCM.PK_CODE_VALUE (Cost=0 Card=1)
  46   41        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.CODE_VALUE (Cost=1 Card=1 Bytes=14)
  47    1      NESTED LOOPS (Cost=9 Card=3 Bytes=117)
  48   47        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.CODE_VALUE (Cost=4 Card=4 Bytes=56)
  49   48          INDEX RANGE SCAN UOBCM.IDX_CV_CDSTATUSID (Cost=2 Card=4)
  50   47        TABLE ACCESS FULL UOBCM.SML_USER (Cost=5 Card=2 Bytes=50)
  51    1      NESTED LOOPS
  52   51        NESTED LOOPS (Cost=5 Card=1 Bytes=39)
  53   52          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.SML_USER (Cost=3 Card=3 Bytes=75)
  54   53            INDEX RANGE SCAN UOBCM.IDX_USR_LOGINID (Cost=1 Card=3)
  55   52          INDEX UNIQUE SCAN UOBCM.PK_CODE_VALUE (Cost=0 Card=1)
  56   51        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.CODE_VALUE (Cost=1 Card=1 Bytes=14)
  57    1      FILTER
  58   57        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.SML_USER (Cost=4 Card=1 Bytes=24)
  59   58          INDEX RANGE SCAN UOBCM.IDX_USR_LOGINID (Cost=1 Card=3)
  60    1      FILTER
  61   60        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.SML_USER (Cost=4 Card=1 Bytes=24)
  62   61          INDEX RANGE SCAN UOBCM.IDX_USR_LOGINID (Cost=1 Card=3)
  63    1      FILTER
  64   63        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.SML_USER (Cost=4 Card=1 Bytes=24)
  65   64          INDEX RANGE SCAN UOBCM.IDX_USR_LOGINID (Cost=1 Card=3)
  66    1      NESTED LOOPS
  67   66        NESTED LOOPS (Cost=28 Card=1 Bytes=95)
  68   67          HASH JOIN (Cost=27 Card=1 Bytes=76)
  69   68            NESTED LOOPS
  70   69              NESTED LOOPS (Cost=24 Card=7 Bytes=476)
  71   70                NESTED LOOPS (Cost=16 Card=8 Bytes=472)
  72   71                  HASH JOIN (Cost=10 Card=12 Bytes=612)
  73   72                    NESTED LOOPS (Cost=6 Card=3 Bytes=129)
  74   73                      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.SML_USER (Cost=2 Card=1 Bytes=19)
  75   74                        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN UOBCM.PK_SML_USER (Cost=1 Card=1)
  76   73                      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.SML_USER (Cost=4 Card=3 Bytes=72)
  77   76                        INDEX RANGE SCAN UOBCM.IDX_USR_LOGINID (Cost=1 Card=3)
  78   72                    INDEX FAST FULL SCAN UOBCM.IDX_TMBR_TMUSERPF (Cost=3 Card=1 K Bytes=8 K)
  79   71                  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.SML_TEAM_CHILD (Cost=1 Card=1 Bytes=8)
  80   79                    INDEX RANGE SCAN UOBCM.IDX_TCHILD_TEAM (Cost=0 Card=1)
  81   70                INDEX UNIQUE SCAN UOBCM.PK_SML_TEAM (Cost=0 Card=1)
  82   69              TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.SML_TEAM (Cost=1 Card=1 Bytes=9)
  83   82                TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.CODE_VALUE (Cost=3 Card=1 Bytes=35)
  84   83                  INDEX RANGE SCAN UOBCM.IDX_CV_CS (Cost=1 Card=19)
  85   84                    TABLE ACCESS FULL UOBCM.CODE_SET (Cost=18 Card=1 Bytes=38)
  86   68            INDEX FAST FULL SCAN UOBCM.IDX_TMBR_TMUSERPF (Cost=3 Card=4 Bytes=32)
  87   67          INDEX UNIQUE SCAN UOBCM.PK_SML_TEAM (Cost=0 Card=1)
  88   66        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.SML_TEAM (Cost=1 Card=1 Bytes=19)
  89    1      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.SML_USER (Cost=4 Card=1 Bytes=43)
  90   89        INDEX RANGE SCAN UOBCM.IDX_USR_LOGINID (Cost=1 Card=3)
  91    1      NESTED LOOPS
  92   91        NESTED LOOPS (Cost=31 Card=1 Bytes=142)
  93   92          NESTED LOOPS (Cost=30 Card=1 Bytes=123)
  94   93            NESTED LOOPS (Cost=29 Card=1 Bytes=104)
  95   94              NESTED LOOPS (Cost=26 Card=3 Bytes=288)
  96   95                NESTED LOOPS (Cost=22 Card=4 Bytes=348)
  97   96                  HASH JOIN (Cost=20 Card=5 Bytes=395)
  98   97                    NESTED LOOPS
  99   98                      NESTED LOOPS (Cost=16 Card=4 Bytes=284)
 100   99                        NESTED LOOPS (Cost=12 Card=4 Bytes=208)
 101  100                          NESTED LOOPS (Cost=10 Card=2 Bytes=88)
 102  101                            NESTED LOOPS (Cost=7 Card=3 Bytes=105)
 103  102                              NESTED LOOPS (Cost=5 Card=4 Bytes=108)
 104  103                                TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.SML_USER (Cost=2 Card=1 Bytes=19)
 105  104                                  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN UOBCM.PK_SML_USER (Cost=1 Card=1)
 106  103                                INDEX FAST FULL SCAN UOBCM.IDX_TMBR_TMUSERPF (Cost=3 Card=4 Bytes=32)
 107  106                                  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.SML_USER (Cost=4 Card=1 Bytes=43)
 108  107                                    INDEX RANGE SCAN UOBCM.IDX_USR_LOGINID (Cost=1 Card=3)
 109  102                              TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.SML_TEAM_CHILD (Cost=1 Card=1 Bytes=8)
 110  109                                INDEX RANGE SCAN UOBCM.IDX_TCHILD_TEAM (Cost=0 Card=1)
 111  101                            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.SML_TEAM (Cost=1 Card=1 Bytes=9)
 112  111                              INDEX UNIQUE SCAN UOBCM.PK_SML_TEAM (Cost=0 Card=1)
 113  111                              TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.CODE_VALUE (Cost=3 Card=1 Bytes=35)
 114  113                                INDEX RANGE SCAN UOBCM.IDX_CV_CS (Cost=1 Card=19)
 115  114                                  TABLE ACCESS FULL UOBCM.CODE_SET (Cost=18 Card=1 Bytes=38)
 116  100                          INDEX RANGE SCAN UOBCM.IDX_TMBR_TMUSERPF (Cost=1 Card=2 Bytes=16)
 117   99                        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN UOBCM.PK_SML_USER (Cost=0 Card=1)
 118   98                      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.SML_USER (Cost=1 Card=1 Bytes=19)
 119   97                    INDEX FAST FULL SCAN UOBCM.IDX_TMBR_TMUSERPF (Cost=3 Card=1 K Bytes=8 K)
 120   96                  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.SML_TEAM_CHILD (Cost=1 Card=1 Bytes=8)
 121  120                    INDEX RANGE SCAN UOBCM.IDX_TCHILD_TEAM (Cost=0 Card=1)
 122   95                TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.SML_TEAM (Cost=1 Card=1 Bytes=9)
 123  122                  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN UOBCM.PK_SML_TEAM (Cost=0 Card=1)
 124  122                  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.CODE_VALUE (Cost=3 Card=1 Bytes=35)
 125  124                    INDEX RANGE SCAN UOBCM.IDX_CV_CS (Cost=1 Card=19)
 126  125                      TABLE ACCESS FULL UOBCM.CODE_SET (Cost=18 Card=1 Bytes=38)
 127   94              INDEX RANGE SCAN UOBCM.IDX_TMBR_TMUSERPF (Cost=1 Card=1 Bytes=8)
 128   93            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.SML_TEAM (Cost=1 Card=1 Bytes=19)
 129  128              INDEX UNIQUE SCAN UOBCM.PK_SML_TEAM (Cost=0 Card=1)
 130   92          INDEX UNIQUE SCAN UOBCM.PK_SML_TEAM (Cost=0 Card=1)
 131   91        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID UOBCM.SML_TEAM (Cost=1 Card=1 Bytes=19)
 132    1      NESTED LOOPS
 133  132        NESTED LOOPS (Cost=28 Card=1 Bytes=95)
 134  133          HASH JOIN (Cost=27 Card=1 Bytes=76)
 135  134            NESTED LOOPS
 136  135              NESTED LOOPS (Cost=24 Card=7 Bytes=476)
 137  136                NESTED LOOPS (
```

Comment: Can you please provide the table creation scripts and some sample data which matches the query

Comment: Honestly, I won't try to understand what you do in this loooooong query, but I see that it contains many sub-queries which might impact the performances.

Comment: The query is quite complex and contains many nested queries. Usually, this is a good way to have the statement running a long time even on relatively small tables. (may be, denormalization could help)
You didn't mention any indexes nor a query plan. Have you chcecked them?

Comment: Also kindly let me know what is the frequency of updates of these tables

Comment: You need to provide the execution plan of the query

Comment: quick win: you don't need a distinct in the subselect used in an IN clause.

Comment: seems you consider yourself more a Java developer (and probably just dumped the Oracle code written by someone else).  Does your company employ Oracle developers?  Just looking at the first select count with multiple nested hierarchy loops, doesn't surprise me this can run a loooong time.  And let me guess, that function (or some set of similar functions like IS_NOTIFICATION_ACCESS_PASSED) are used is the looooong running query (executed for every row).  Yikes

Comment: Where to begin?  The main query contains 19 subqueries.  Makes multiple complex function calls from the WHERE clause.  Uses TO_CHAR in the WHERE clause, forcing a full table scan.  Uses SUBSTR in the WHERE clause, forcing a full table scan.  Uses **LIKE** in the WHERE clause, once again forcing a full table scan.  Uses REGEXP functions.  Hierarchical subqueries.  `SELECT DISTINCT` on a five-way join.  Please post the execution plan.

Comment: @tbone - the function IS_NOTIFICATION_ACCESS_PASSED is called twice from the WHERE clause in the main query.  In addition, the main query has queries nested five deep, i.e. query invokes subquery invokes subquery invokes subquery invokdes subquery.  I'm still waiting for the query plan.

Answer (score 0):

This is a reasonably large query with lots of sub queries, you'd need to do an explain plan on it and then start chipping away at the "slow" bits. It may be query to extract the logic from your stored procedure and embed it in your query. 100,000 rows is not much, you should be able to tune this a lot.